# How to get all total result data by youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using Youtube Api to get all videos details of channel

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,id&key=XXXXXXXX&channelId=UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA&order=date&maxResults=50

[You can see response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZqET.png)

In the first response, I can see there are 761525 results and nextPageToken is also there but using that next page token I can max 300 to 400 video details after that API not giving me any result.

So is there any other to get all the videos details? Or anything is missing by me?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube returns a soft limit of 500 videos for any search request.

If there are more than that in totalResults, you can split the search query using the *publishedAfter* and *publishedBefore* filters to loop through dates by day/week/month etc., making sure each 'time window' returns less than the 500 limit. Eventually, you will get all results.

Comment: No, it's not working by using publishedAfter and publishedBefore. In this what happen that given the same total results but in items that will only date match data.

Comment: Yes that's the idea. Loop the dates to get them all.

Comment: But one thing is I am facing is that from API I m getting only 473 videos when I try to count in youtube page and I found there is 1200 video. So have you any idea about that difference???

Answer (score 0):

After the first time you request an API call, for example this:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,id&key=XXXXXXXX&channelId=UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA&order=date&maxResults=50

You need to fetch the nextPageToken parameter of that (1st) result , and feed it to the next (2nd) request. Let's suppose the nextPageToken of the first result is ABCDEFG, your next request must be like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&pageToken=ABCDEFG,id&key=XXXXXXXX&channelId=UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA&order=date&maxResults=50

See that after snippet I've added &pageToken=ABCDEFG. And then you take again the string of the parameter nextPageToken of this (2nd) result and feed it to your next (3rd) request. So you need to do this with a while loop until the nextPageToken is null, which means you've hit the border number (in your case 761525 results). Or you can fix this by a certain number of results that you get.

Summary:

1. Request your first API call
2. Make a loop
3. Take the nextPageToken value
4. For your next requests, add after snippet this part &pageToken=
5. Write the value of nextPageToken after &pageToken=
6. Repeat from step 2 until a certain condition (until you get all the results or just a certain number of results)

Comment: Yes, but it's only working for some pages only

Comment: That's because not all pages have a next page. For example the end page doesn't have a next page because well, it's the last one...
There are also pages which don't have a lot of results, therefore no need for a next page.
I think it's enough for you to handle the case if the attribute nextPageToken exists, then fetch the data for the next page, if it doesn't, then break the loop there (don't continue any further with requesting APIs)

Comment: Also, be careful of the daily quota, you can only request so many free APIs per day, if you reach the limit, then the response is NOT gonna be 200 (not OK).

Comment: Yes, I checked for the limit,

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search here you can see I directly used search API. SO for this API have limitations about the data.

So now looking to channel and playlist API.